# How to call a dynamic day in sql?

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table I want to pull all date records before the most recent Friday. I know you can use sysdate (or getdate) to pull the current day, but all the solutions to similar questions I've looked at explicitly specify the numeric day of the week in the query. Todays Thursday so the below would work, but is there a dynamic alternative to this?

```
SELECT *
FROM table
WHERE datefield < sysdate - 6
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use:

```sql
SELECT NEXT_DAY(TRUNC(SYSDATE) - 7, 'FRIDAY') AS last_friday
FROM   DUAL;
```

However, if someone tries to query the data and is using a different language then you will get an error. I.e.:

```sql
ALTER SESSION SET NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE = 'FRENCH';

SELECT NEXT_DAY(TRUNC(SYSDATE) - 7, 'FRIDAY') AS last_friday
FROM   DUAL;
```

Outputs:

> ```
> ORA-01846: not a valid day of the week
> ```

---

A solution that works regardless of the language is to compare the day to the start of the ISO week (which is always a Monday):

```sql
SELECT TRUNC(SYSDATE, 'IW')
       + CASE WHEN SYSDATE - TRUNC(SYSDATE, 'IW') < 5
         THEN -3
         ELSE +4
         END AS last_friday
FROM   DUAL;
```

Outputs (with the `NLS_DATE_FORMAT` set to `YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS (DY)`):

> | LAST_FRIDAY |
> | --- |
> | 2022-01-14 00:00:00 (FRI) |

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=e442c5eb7ab1fb234e272b853c5fedd4)*

---

Your query would be:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM table
WHERE datefield < TRUNC(SYSDATE, 'IW')
                  + CASE WHEN SYSDATE - TRUNC(SYSDATE, 'IW') < 5
                    THEN -3
                    ELSE +4
                    END
```

Comment: Will give it a try... but just want to verify, if I run this Sun-Thur, it will always use the last Friday as the filter date? So whether I ran this today or on 1-15-2022, the date field should be filtered by dates < 1-14-2022

Comment: @chicagobeast12 Why don't you try it and find out? [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=58b58b718c42f0ce2956cd59225b704e)

Answer (score 0):

`next_day` function might help.

```
SQL> with test (datum) as
  2    -- sample data; this January up to today
  3    (select trunc(sysdate, 'mm') + level - 1
  4     from dual
  5     connect by level <= 20
  6    )
  7  select to_char(datum, 'dd.mm.yyyy, dy') datum
  8  from test
  9  where datum < next_day(sysdate - 7, 'FRIDAY')
 10  order by datum;

DATUM
------------------------
01.01.2022, sat
02.01.2022, sun
03.01.2022, mon
04.01.2022, tue
05.01.2022, wed
06.01.2022, thu
07.01.2022, fri
08.01.2022, sat
09.01.2022, sun
10.01.2022, mon
11.01.2022, tue
12.01.2022, wed
13.01.2022, thu
14.01.2022, fri

14 rows selected.

SQL>
```